# How can i get my result in histogram(Graph) in mapreduce using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

When I run this code I am getting an error in reduce part on a cluster.I am taking probability
and using Matplotlib to get my output graphical but it will be failed. I am running this code on Google Cloud cluster. my data in excel csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""mapper.py"""
import sys

# Get input lines from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    #line = line.strip()

    # Split it into tokens
    #tokens = line.split()

    #Get probability_mass values
    for prob in line:
        print("None\t{}".format(prob))
        #print(str(probability_mass)+ '\t1')
        #print('%s\t%s' % (probability_mass, None))
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""reducer.py"""
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(float)

# Get input from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    #line = line.strip()

    # skip empty lines
    if not line:
        continue  

    # parse the input from mapper.py
    k,v = line.split('\t', 1)
    counts[v] += 1
total = (float(sum(counts.values())))
#total = sum(counts.values())
probability_mass = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
#print(probability_mass)
grad = probability_mass.keys()
prob = probability_mass.values()
print(str(grad))
print(str(prob))
   #bins = 20
plt.hist(prob,bins=20, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
   #plt.plot(bins, hist, 'r--')
plt.xlabel('Probability')
plt.ylabel('Number Of Students')
plt.title('Histogram of Students Grade')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your results to a file, then download it and plot it as two separate steps.

MapReduce has no GUI and you shouldn't have each reducer task trying to generate a plot

Or you can export the results to some GCP tool like BigQuery or Datastore where you can plug in proper BI tools for visual analytics